# Use Entity Framework to access data from a Web service?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

So I've used Entity Framework as a data abstraction layer on SQL databases, avoiding the need to write SQL queries, but using (something like?) LINQ instead. And then EF translates all that to SQL and connects to databases automatically. It's a very easy way to manage data given a model.

Now I am making a REST client, and I am thinking of using EF for accessing that as well.

So how do I make this thing connect to a REST API, instead of an SQL database? Googling Entity Framework together with REST only told me how to make a REST **server** use EF for accessing a **database**. I want to use EF on a the **client** side that accesses a **Web server**, that in turn accesses the data.

So I expect something like writing model.Users.Where(...) and it being translated to a GET /api/users?filter... HTTP request (instead of classic SELECT * FROM Users WHERE... SQL query).

I tried creating an "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" like I do usually but all options it provides require me to specify a connection string - this only applies to databases. I want an API endpoint, not an SQL connection string.

AFAIK EF connects to a "DataSet" object (created automatically and connected to a database), but then again I don't know how to make those use REST API. Do I need to write my own class that implements DataSet, and somehow make EF use THAT? Everything I've seen about DataSets also seem to literally imply SQL databases. Grrr.

Sorry for long post with such a simple question. So does someone know **how to make Entity Framework use a REST service instead of a database**? It should be so simple. After all, Microsoft calls it a **data access** abstraction layer. Not **database access**.

Comment: Use the right tool for the right purpose. Like @IlyaKorover said: EF is an ORM framework. If you want to achieve something like that then you'll have to write your own wrapper.

Comment: Did you ever make this work with the Entity Framework? I think it would be an interesting solution where you would want to connect to a SQL-based server directly while being in a local network, but want to use a (proxy) web API otherwise (e. g. to avoid firewall issues when trying to connect to a SQL server directly). In both cases you would want to stay with same ORM then, of course. Therefore curious if you made that work! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best start to you is to look on the [OData protocol](http://www.odata.org/) that has out of the box support by [ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api). Check [that link](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-select-expand-and-value) for good tutorials that should help you.

Comment: The OData protocol you linked has NOTHING to do with EntityFramework, right? So, does Entiry Framework ONLY support databases? Because that's exactly what Microsoft has NOT said about it. They said it is a GENERAL data access abstraction. Database is not general, it's special case.

Comment: Oh. You gave me wrong information. OData seems to be for making ASP.NET web applications - that is, it's used on the SERVER side. In my case, the Web server / REST API might not even be written in .NET. I need EF on the CLIENT side (a WPF app for PC) to access the Web service (connect to the said Web server), while the Web server is the ONLY one connecting to the database.

Comment: I think I got your point, but I am not sure, why do you need ORM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) in that case? Actually EF is an ORM framework.

Comment: "Actually EF is an ORM framework" Microsoft NEVER said that in their description of EntityFramework. Rather, by what they say, one would conclude it's NOT an ORM and does NOT exclusively work with relational data. But having tried everything, it seems it does... Microsoft lied again. -_-

Comment: Actually, it seems you do not know the difference between EF and LINQ. [What is EF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: NOW I see they did finally admit that EF is an ORM, not a general data access framework. Before your comment I did not know about that page. Who knows where have I been looking for EF description (possibly on MSDN or even in NuGet package description in VS), or what misinformation did I remember... Yes, LINQ is the more general case, with SQL-like syntax for using whatever class supports the needed methods...

Comment: You know, I still am intrigued by this possibility of EF abstracting Web calls. Theoretically, this should be possible; create a Data Provider/Driver for EF that makes a web connection and pass on the query/command. What is _complex_ is the implementation. This Driver must translate the LINQ statements into an HTTP Request ([HQL](https://github.com/HubSpot/httpQL), IT EXISTS!). BUT, will developers of the world agree to conform to those rules when creating their Web APIs? What about complex OR and JOIN queries? Can this Driver be ubiquitous enough? :)

Comment: Found another SO question (same answer though), so just tagging it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318361