# .NET Core Entity Framework with a REST API as Datasource?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

**Situation:** I have two Applications. One is an API and the other is my Web Application.

> **edit**: only the API has Access to the Database

**Idea:** Is it possible to also use Entity Framework in my Web Application with the API as Datasource instead of an actual Database?

Answer (score 0):

If I good understand your case, you have two applications which are connected to the same database? I think you have two options:

1. First is create third project "Repository" with database access logic and use it in both applications.
2. Use your API as source for WebApplication Data - just from actions in WebApp controllers make HTTP calls to your api (eg. http://localhost/api/path).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I think you missunderstood my case (see my edits). I know how to access the Api but I'm a lazy person and I don't want to write a CRUD, so I thought I could use EF to access the data through the API.

Comment: EF is ORM to access database, there is no way to use it as API client. I Think you can try the first option i've proposed and make wrapper to access database. Then you are be able to use it in both projects.